# Field must be grouped or aggregated: Product__c

Tags: error-messages

```
List<AggregateResult> ARListCurrIssue = [select AccountId , Count(Id) CaseCount,Product__c from Case where AccountId In:AccIdUpd and IsClosed != True group By AccountId ];
```

Comment: Each field in the `select` clause should be either grouped or aggregated in the aggregate query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `GROUP BY <fields>`, then you can use ***only*** specify those fields as-is in the `SELECT` clause. For example, if you use `GROUP BY AccountId, Product__c,` then you can specify `SELECT AccountId, Product__c,` and all other fields in the `SELECT` clause should be aggregated (SUM, MIN, MAX, COUNT etc.). If you specify fields (that are not grouped by) without aggregate function in the SELECT clause, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: can you write query for that...i tried it but its still shown error

Comment: Following are valid aggregate queries:  "select AccountId , Count(Id) CaseCount from Case where AccountId In:AccIdUpd and IsClosed != True group By AccountId" or "select AccountId, Product__c, Count(Id) CaseCount from Case where AccountId In:AccIdUpd and IsClosed != True group By AccountId, Product__c". The SOQL query depends on your expected result. Could you elaborate on the expected result?